# Displaying data angularjs ng-repeat in li

Tags: html, css, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a problem with loading data in an ng-repeat ...
I managed to use a Timeline:

[Problem displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLVWE.png)

But as you can see, all the data is not well displayed. I found on the internet  that it was maybe caused by the fact that the css was loaded before the data, and this impacts the height of the li...

How can I display the data properly ?

http://jsfiddle.net/cdric0701/htnkwvyL/ 
`<li ng-repeat="event in events">`

The code is working here with the version of angular, the content fits the li but mine don't as you can see on the picture ...

Comment: Post your code with JSFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cdric0701/htnkwvyL/

Comment: You should consider changing the question title to "Displaying data angularjs ng-repeat in li" because "Loading" is somewhat misleading IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

add css `.timeline-body {overflow-wrap: break-word;}` and you also have to modify Controller.
Working fiddle ling : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htnkwvyL/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesn't resolve my problem ... I managed to do what you told me but on a Angular 1.4.7 this doesn't work. I still have at one moment, the text cut ...

Comment: I did not understand actually what problem you are facing now. Please explain with more detail. Please add fiddle Or if not possible then add screen shot.

Comment: I didn't managed to solve the problem so I used another library https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-timeline